# What does "fold into somebody" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, phrasal-verbs

This context comes form the video game "Divinity Original Sin II"

This dialogue appears after two of the characters from the game have sex and lie in bed.

"Lohse yawns and stretches, arching her whole body like a cat. She **folds into you**, her head on your chest, arm draped around your body"

**"fold"**

7. to embrace or clasp; enfold: *to fold someone in one's arms.*(Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary)

But the following **preposition "into"** complicates things for me.
Maybe it's this phrasal verb?

**fold (something) into (something)**

1. To bend or crease something into a particular shape or object.
   He loves origami and can fold paper into all kinds of animals.(Farlex Dictionary of Idioms)

Perhaps it's metaphorical and it means that she bent herself into his shape because she embraced him so tight?

Comment: It's a bit of both. First she stretches, and then folds herself into a complementary shape. I picture someone snuggled into a larger person's frame, with one arm around their waist.

Comment: It means the same as to "snuggle into" someone, but without the "cute" feeling of "snuggle".